# Is $f'(c)=0$ necessary condition for an inflection point at $c$?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that an inflection point occurs when there is a change of sign of the second derivative. I have tried to prove that if there is a change of sign in $f''$ at $c$ then $f'(c) = 0$ but I have not succeeded.

I'm also aware that there can be an inflection point when the first derivative is undefined. Like:

$$
    f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    \sqrt{x},& x\geq 0\\
    -\sqrt{-x}, & x \lt 0
\end{cases}
$$

So in principle I would say it's not a necessary condition. But could we say that $f'(c) = 0$ or either $f'$ is undefined is a necessary condition? How can I prove that I cannot have $f'(c) = 5$ and an inflection point at $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong, you don't necessarily need $f'(c)=0$ at an inflection point, we can see this by looking at $f(x)=x^3+x$ which has positive derivative everywhere but an inflection point at $x=0$.

However, by the intermediate value theorem, if we assume $f''$ exists, at least around the inflection point, it is true that an inflection point must have $f''(c)=0$.

Comment: **Assuming $f''$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

The condition for an inflection point is when $f''(x) =0$, what do you mean by a change of sign? you can't prove that in an inflection point occurs also when f'(x) because it's usually wrong[[image: f(x) =<span class=]$x^3-x$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66lGH.jpg)

In the picture is $f(x) =x^3-x$ with its inflection point and its min/max points
$$f'(x)=3x^2-1=0$$
$$3x^2=1$$
$$x^2=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
And $$f''(x) =6x=0$$
$$x=0$$